# How do I fix row count sql bad interaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I've set this sql query on a heroku database "clip" (postgresql)

```
select count(table1) as colname1, count(table2) as colname2 from table1, table2;
```

Each table has 2 rows, and the solution of the count is 4 in each column value.

```
--------------------
colname1 | colname2
  4      |    4
--------------------
```

What am I missing either on sql basics or DB specific?

Comment: Just a side note. You would have probably noticed quickly this was not correct if you habitually used ANSI join syntax rather than a (obsolete) comma separated list of tables in the FROM clause. You would have "from table1 join table2" but on what? Seems the only option would "from table1 cross join table2" which you would have recognized as incorrect.  Learn to use the modern (only 29 years old) syntax. May take some getting used to but it is actually easier to use and **much** less error prone.

Comment: Thank you very much. This very week I was improving in my use of LEFT JOIN clauses. You are right, I'm not very used to the ANSI join syntax at this very moment.

Comment: You are welcome. Stay with it, once you adapt it just becomes natural, and your queries improve. I know - it took me a while to adapt. I find it unfortunate and disturbing that both Postgres and Oracle documentation still primarily have the pre ANSI format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for.

```
select cnt1, cnt2
from ( select count(1) cnt1 from table1)  a,
     ( select count(1) cnt2 from table2) b;
```

Answer (score 2):

you are making a cross join, so it is counting the row count of table 1 multiplied by the row count of table 2.

Comment: Omg, I suspected that was what was happening. Was it made because of the 2 tables in the from clause?